# Difference between planet_osm_polygon and planet_osm_point tables

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

What's the difference between the planet_osm_polygon and planet_osm_point tables? I find similar columns in both tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the names: `planet_osm_point` contains point features from OSM, that is, nodes that have tags on them. Columns in both tables are tags, plus `way` for geometry.

`Planet_osm_polygon` contains polygons and processed multipolygons (so you don't need to collect multipolygons yourself). So, for example, building contours would be included in `_polygon` table, while shop nodes have to be collected from `_point`.

I don't know why it was decided to split points and polygons (and lines) into different tables. This probably allows disk space optimization, for tags allowed for those types of geometries are different (see `default.style` from osm2pgsql directory).

Comment: Well, I'd assume that has something to do with the possibility to work with the data as shapefiles. Whereas tab files can hold points, lines, polygons in one datalayer, shapefiles are distinctly only point, only lines, only polygons.  For your example shop nodes: there could be a polygon to show WHERE it lies and what shape it has, but the point data with the shop name allows for a POINT dataset to be styled with icons (i.e. icons for shops, gas stations, parking lots) which would be harder to do in the polygons.

Comment: Don't expect that shops always are found in the nodes table. They can be stored as polygon-only in the database too. You have to build centroids from them separately.